# Distinct count with dynamic start date and end date

Tags: sql

I have this dataset

Webinar:

```
id    title     start              end
1     A         2020-01-01 10:00   2020-01-01 12:00
2     B         2020-01-02 15:00   2020-01-02 17:30
```

User_activity

```
id    user_id    webinar_id   created_at
1     1          1            2020-01-01 10:01
2     2          1            2020-01-01 12:01
3     1          2            2020-01-02 15:01
```

I want to know the duration of each webinar in minutes and number of unique user that view webinar in start time and end time of each webinar

for example:

```
id    title     start              end                duration   view
1     A         2020-01-01 10:00   2020-01-01 12:00   120        1
2     B         2020-01-02 15:00   2020-01-02 17:30   150        1
```

User 2 is not counted because he is exceed the end time

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: it is mysql dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select a.id,title,start,end,timestampdiff(MINUTE,end,start) as duration,
       count(distinct user_id) as view
from Webinar a join User_activity u on a.id=u.webinar_id
where created_at>=start and created_at<=end
group by a.id,title,start,end
```

Comment: I don't think you need to sum the timestampdiff; if there is a webinar form 12:00 to 1:00 and 5 people viewed it would add it all ang give 5 hours

Comment: It is work for distinct count but the duration still error. Incorect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: @OctavianWR, I've updated the answer - you can give a try

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TIMESTAMDIFF` function if the datatype is datetime:

```sql
SELECT w.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, w.start, w.end) AS duration, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM User_activity ua 
      WHERE ua.webinar_id = w.id 
      AND ua.created_at BETWEEN w.start and w.end
    ) AS `view`
FROM Webinar w
```

Updated: `COUNT` function with `DISTINCT` instead `COUNT(*)` is used to count unique users.